C#: MqttClient errors: Client does not contain a definition
I use Visual Studio 2022 with Windows 11 and C#
I have installed the MQTTnet ManagedClient Package:
NuGet\Install-Package MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient -Version 4.3.6.1152

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient.4.3.6.1152' with respect to project 'Test', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'

Gathering dependency information took 613 ms

Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient.4.3.6.1152' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'

Successfully installed 'MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient 4.3.6.1152' 

But when I  use the following code, I get some errors "MqttClient does not contain a definition for ..." :
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Client.Options;  // <== error: 'options' does not exist in namespace


using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

        // Configure options to connect without credentials
        var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
            .WithClientId("Client1")
            .WithTcpServer("broker.hivemq.com", 1883) // HiveMQ public broker
            .WithCleanSession()
            .Build();

//==> error: 'IMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'UseConnectedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'UseConnectedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IMqttClient' could be found 
            mqttClient.UseConnectedHandler(async e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully with MQTT broker.");
            
                // Subscribe to a topic
                    await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(new MQTTnet.Client.Subscribing.MqttClientSubscribeOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithTopicFilter("test/topic")
                    .Build());
            
                Console.WriteLine("Subscribed to topic.");
            });
            
//==> error: 'IMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'UseDisconnectedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'UseDisonnectedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IMqttClient' could be found 
            mqttClient.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from MQTT broker.");
            });
            
//==> error: 'IMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IMqttClient' could be found
            mqttClient.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received message:");
                Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {e.ApplicationMessage.Topic}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload)}");
            });

Why do I get these errors ?
I've tried delete and re-install the Nuget package and change the target framework (.NET 4.7 to 4.8), clean project, rebuild project but this did not fix the errors.

Have you tried installing 'MQTTnet' package? Depending on what version of .csproj you're using, you might need to do that. Give it a try we never know ;)
'MQTTnet' is a dependency of 'MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient', it must have that package to work
